# Getting the sorted playlistItems from google youtube api v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using google youtube data api v3 to get videos in a playlist. Everything is fine but I want the final result to be sorted by date. How can I accomplish this?

Following is my query

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key={my_api_key}&playlistId=PLxtF39cCOsxehnvwzlYT0R5h8dh4y3Lp2&part=snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=50&fields=items(snippet/title,snippet/publishedAt,snippet/resourceId/videoId)
```

Comment: You'll have to sort things yourself once you get the results back; the playlistItems endpoint does not provide a way to do so (it returns the item in reverse chronological order based on when the video was added to the playlist).

Comment: Where did you find this information about the returned order?

Answer (score 2):

Since this option to "pre-sort" the results from API is not yet available, you would have to manually do it.

- Use https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems to grab all the videoID's of the current playlist.
- If the playlist is longer than 50 videos, then create a loop that first stores the totalResults into a variable.
- Loop through each set of 50, until all videoID's have been fetched using nextPageToken.
- Now you should have an array with all videoID's stored inside it.
- Sort it how you want (newest first would be a simple reverse),
- Use https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos to fetch all the info from each video, in sets of 50. Do same loop as above.

In theory this should work. I will be testing this out later on.

Answer (score 0):

This feature request is reported internally. You can [create a ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=youtube-api) to track.

Answer (score 0):

You can set sort order in the playlist settings API will return results in that order.